# delete the id from combobox during runtime after deleting from database in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mysql

```
Private Sub btn_remove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_remove.Click
    Dim Query As String
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Query = "delete from table where screen_id='" & cmb_id.Text & "' "
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, mysqlconn)
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Record is Successfully deleted")

    Else
        MsgBox("Record is not deleted")
    End If
    mysqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```

i select id from combobox .depending upon the selected id i do delete from the database.Above code explains the same but i want to delete that deleted id from combobox as well during runtime(after deleting from database)

THanks

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple . After you delete the id load the data in the combo box again..

```
Private Sub btn_remove_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_remove.Click
    Dim Query As String
    mysqlconn.Open()
    Query = "delete from table where screen_id='" & cmb_id.Text & "' "
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, mysqlconn)
    Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Record is Successfully deleted")
**===> load the data here or call the function that load the data in the combo box**
    Else
        MsgBox("Record is not deleted")
    End If
    mysqlconn.Close()
End Sub
```